# executable 'spawner' not found on the libexec directory '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager' problem

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I almost successfully migrated my project from Noetic to Foxy and now I'm to launch my packages. I have the following problem:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/mikita/.ros/log/2022-11-14-03-39-50-208073-ubuntu-11543
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=SubstitutionFailure("executable 'spawner' not found on the libexec directory '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager' ")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
[Previous line repeated 1 more time]
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 453, in execute
    ret = super().execute(context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 823, in execute
    self.__expand_substitutions(context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 668, in __expand_substitutions
    cmd = [perform_substitutions(context, x) for x in self.__cmd]
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    cmd = [perform_substitutions(context, x) for x in self.__cmd]
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 232, in perform_substitution
    return substitution.perform(self)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/substitutions/executable_in_package.py", line 84, in perform
    raise SubstitutionFailure(
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: executable 'spawner' not found on the libexec directory '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager'
```

This is how my launch file looks like:

```
import os
import sys

import launch
import launch_ros.actions
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    ld = launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='controller_manager',
            executable='spawner',
            name='controller_spawner',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[
                {
                    '/minicar/controller/enable_odom_tf': 'true'
                },
                {
                    'robot_description': "minicar.gazebo.xacro"
                }
            ]
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            parameters=[
                {
                    '/minicar/controller/enable_odom_tf': 'true'
                },
                {
                    'robot_description': "minicar.gazebo.xacro"
                }
            ]
        ),
        launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
            launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(
                    'minicar_control'), 'launch/mux.launch.py')
            )
        )
    ])
    return ld


if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_launch_description()
```

I've tried solution that suggested [here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/issues/350), still not working. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409350/executable-%27spawner%27-not-found-on-the-libexec-directory-%27/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager%27-problem/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There could be following two issues. Please check:

1. Please install `controller-manager` as shown below:

   ```
    sudo apt install ros-foxy-controller-manager
   ```
2. The executable name seems `spawner.py` based on the [documentation](https://control.ros.org/foxy/doc/ros2_control/controller_manager/doc/userdoc.html#helper-scripts).

   ```
    ros2 run controller_manager spawner.py -h
   ```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-11-15**:
It works.  Thank you very much!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-15**:
I am glad you made it work!